# dependency between multiple kendo grids

Tags: kendo-grid

If I have multiple kendo grids on the same page each loaded by ajax in its own partial view. How can I create a dependency between the 2 grids, so the 2nd grid won't load until the first grid has completed?

Can I use an ajax async callback, or and event to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "completed", you mean it has data, this will probably do the trick.

1. Set `autobind` to false in both grids' initialization:

   ```
   autoBind: false
   ```
2. Use the `dataBound` event to chain the data load of the second grid:

   ```js
   function gridOne_dataBound(e) {
       var grid2 = $("#gridTwo").data("kendoGrid");
       //modify grid2's dataSource if needed
       grid2.dataSource.fetch();
   }

   //put this code after where you instantiate your grids
   var grid1 = $("#gridOne").data("kendoGrid");
   grid1.bind("dataBound", gridOne_dataBound);
   grid1.dataSource.fetch();
   ```

You can do the dataBound event binding in the grid init itself, but I did it externally to make it clearer. See here for [more info](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-dataBound). Hope it helps.